# Error: `path` does not exist: ‘MIS_655_RS_T3_Wholesale_Customers’

Tags: import, directory

I imported my excel file into R Environment and saved the path by creating a new file in R scrip. However, when I tried to check my directory and load the dataset, I received the following message " Error: `path` does not exist: ‘MIS_655_RS_T3_Wholesale_Customers’
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you missed the format of your dataset, eg. csv, xlsx.

I suggest you first set your file as working directory, then the following code might help you with it.

`Dat_customers <- readxl::read_excel("MIS_655_RS_T3_Wholesale_Customers.xlsx")`